# Can we start another page without writing a session_start()?

Tags: php, mysql

If we start `session_start()` on `login.php` page and then relocate on another page `say for example home.php` and without writing `session_start()` on home.php. Then, how we can maintain home.php within session. can you please help? I want home.php to be maintained within the session started on login.php without writing `session_start()`.

Comment: So... You want to use the session state without having to use the session state?

Comment: @Devid. Nope not like that..but can we maintain the code only session start once and other pages are also maintain on that session without writing or session_start() on another pages...?

Comment: Unless there's a setting in `php.ini` to always have session turned on (which, if there is, might not be a great practice) then no.  What you can do, as in the answers below, is move `session_start()` into a common code file (with any other common code you might have) and include that file in your pages.

Answer (score 1):

This will start another page, and continue with the current one:

```
<php 
    include("yourPHPfileName.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have a shared PHP file for all your pages.

For example,

```
<?php 
session_start();
// other shared settings
```

And on your actual page, you could require this shared settings file like so.

```
<?php 
require_once('settings.php');

// Your page goes here
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php for more information and examples

Answer (score -1):

You could split your page up and include a header with the session_start() command in.

Comment: Sorry, but This is not an answer, its a comment!